# Regex: Opposite of group match

Tags: regex

this expression

```
(^\+\d{2})_\1
```

would match

```
+32_+32
```

How can I make it match

```
+32_+44
```

Comment: do you want the second part must not equal of first group match or just want to match both of the patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the opposite, you might use a negative lookahead `(?!\1)` asserting not the value of group 1 and then match a `+` and 2 digits

```
^(\+\d{2})_(?!\1)\+\d{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMQYzJ/1)

If you want to match an underscore followed by 2 digits, you don't need the first capturing group and you can match if afterwards.

```
^\+\d{2}_\+\d{2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/50vNiw/1)